# Check if functions have been called in unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Hi I'm trying to write some unit tests in Jest for a module I write, but kind of stuck currently and need some advice how to continue.

```
export const submitOrder = async (body, key) => {
  const clientRepo = new ClientRepository(db)
  const companyRepo = new CompanyRepository(db)

  const company = await getCompanyByKey(
    companyRepo,
    key
  );

  const client = await createClient(
    clientRepo,
    body
  );

  await addClientToCompany(
    companyRepo,
    client.id,
    company.id
  );

  .. More things
}
```

I can easily test each function(`getCompanyByKey`, `createClient` & `addClientToCompany`) by passing down a mocked repository.

But I would also like to test my "flow" of the `submitOrder` function, by checking if my repository functions have been called. But I would then need the instance of each repository, which I don't instantiate until my `submitOrder` function.

Something like this, which is similar how I unit test my functions.

```
jest.mock('../repositories/ClientRepository');
jest.mock('../repositories/CompanyRepository');

test('should be able to submit an order', async () => {
  const apiKey = 'mocked-super-key';
  const body = getMockData();

  const result = await submitOrder(body, apiKey);
  expect(result).toMatchSnapshot();
  expect(CompanyRepository.findByKey).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(ClientRepository.create).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(CompanyRepository.addClient).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Do you have any tips of how I can test if my repositories have been called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe is one of the motivating factors behind dependency injection.

As a single example: your `submitOrder()` code uses `new` to directly instantiate a client repository of the specific implementation `ClientRepository`.  Instead, it could declare that it has a dependency - it needs an object that implements the interface of a client repository.  It could then allow for such an object to be supplied by the surrounding environment (a "dependency injection container" in buzzword-ese).  Then during testing you would create and provide ("inject") a mock implementation instead of the real implementation.

This has the added benefit that if you ever have to be able to select between multiple "real" implementations, you're already set up to do that too.

There are many ways to achieve this.  It can be as simple as a design pattern, or for a more complete solution you could use a dependency injection framework.

If you absolutely cannot refactor your code for this practice, then JavaScript is dynamic enough that you can probably cobble together a way to intercept the invocation of `new` and thereby simulate dependency injection.

Comment: Yeah sure, I think I understood you. Something like: 
`container.register('companyRepository', new CompanyRepository())`?


But wouldn't it overwrite my mock if I do the same but `container.register('companyRepository', new MockCompanyRepository())`in my test suite?

Comment: I guess we're making conflicting assumptions about where `container.register('companyRepository', new CompanyRepository())` would happen.  It's a line that would never execute during testing.

Comment: Right, so I would need some config file to point which dependencies a function require and in which environment(production & test)?

Comment: Something like that.  Solving the problem of mapping dependencies to concrete implementations / instances is a big part of the job of a full-fledged dependency injection framework.  Typically you end up with some sort of initialization phase that runs in production to set up the "real" instances to be injected for all manner of dependency, but you don't run that in unit tests. Instead each test case sets up the dependencies for the code under test.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a mock implementation factory as a second parameter to `jest.mock`, [as described in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options).

You can use this to mock out the methods that you want to check to have been called.

Try this:

```
jest.mock('../repositories/CompanyRepository', () => {
    findByKey: jest.fn(),
    addClient: jest.jn()
});

const mockCreate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('../repositories/CompanyRepository', () => class {
    create(...args) {
        mockCreate(...args);
    }
});

test('should be able to submit an order', async () => {
    const apiKey = 'mocked-super-key';
    const body = getMockData();

    const result = await submitOrder(body, apiKey);
    expect(result).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(CompanyRepository.findByKey).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(ClientRepository.create).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(CompanyRepository.addClient).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Since *CompanyRepository* is created with “new”, we use a class definition in this case and pass in a mock function that is called when the “create” method is invoked.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because my `CompanyRepository ` is instantiated with __new__ keyword. Though I can create mimic mocks in a `__mock__` folder and replace them. But I still cant test my repositories functions.

Comment: OK, you can also have the mock factory return a class. I've updated my code example, try it please